# Cosmos Table API - perform custom scheduled backup

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using a Cosmos Table API application and I need to backup all the data from all the tables every 15 minutes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ADF only supports cosmos db [sql api and mongo api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db),not for table api,it seems that you have to consider using [Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#AzureTableSource).

You could follow above example command-line:

> dt.exe /s:AzureTable
>   /s.ConnectionString:"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=;AccountKey=" /s.Table:metrics /s.InternalFields:All
>   /s.Filter:"PartitionKey eq 'Partition1' and RowKey gt '00001'"
>   /s.Projection:ObjectCount;ObjectSize  /t:DocumentDBBulk
>   /t.ConnectionString:" AccountEndpoint=;AccountKey=;Database=;"
>   /t.Collection:metrics /t.CollectionThroughput:2500

Then turn it into a bat file and set it to Windows Timing Task.