# Use Azure Cosmos DB Migration Tool to export from Azure Table API to json

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, data-migration, cosmos

I want to migrate the data from Cosmos Table API to a json file.

I have copied the PRIMARY CONNECTION STRING from the portal and this is the command I am trying to run from using the migration tool:

```
dt.exe /s:DocumentDB /s.ConnectionString:"PRIMARY CONNECTION STRING" /s.Collection:application /t:JsonFile
```

OR:

```
dt.exe /s:DocumentDB /s.ConnectionString:"PRIMARY CONNECTION STRING;Database=TablesDB" /s.Collection:application /t:JsonFile
```

and I receive this error:

**Critical error: DocumentDB account end-point URL should be provided as part of the connection string**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> Critical error: DocumentDB account end-point URL should be provided as
>   part of the connection string

Based on this error,the account url is lack in the connection string.You could follow the example from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data):

> dt.exe /s:JsonFile /s.Files:.\Sessions.json /t:DocumentDBBulk
>   /t.ConnectionString:"AccountEndpoint=;AccountKey=;Database=;"

Please check the `AccountEndpoint=` in your connection string and try again.

Comment: I want to move from Cosmos Table API to a json file.

Comment: I want to move from Cosmos Table API to a json file. But you gave me the answer I needed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202455/cosmos-table-api-perform-custom-scheduled-backup

Comment: Command to export data from Table API to json file:

dt.exe /s:AzureTable /s.ConnectionString:"Connection String" /s.Table:application /s.InternalFields:All /t:JsonFile /t.File:application.json

Comment: @Angela Your error indicates that you provided uncomplete connection string,i just wanna suggest you checking the connection string.

Comment: The problem was that I was using /s:DocumentDB instead of /s:AzureTable